# foreach not applicable to expression type

Tags: java

what does this error mean? and how do i solve it?

foreach not applicable to expression type.

im am trying to write a method find(). that find a string in a linkedlist

```
public class Stack<Item>
{
    private Node first;

    private class Node
    {
        Item item;
        Node next;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return ( first == null );
    }

    public void push( Item item )
    {
        Node oldfirst = first;
        first = new Node();
        first.item = item;
        first.next = oldfirst;
    }

    public Item pop()
    {
        Item item = first.item;
        first = first.next;
        return item;
    }
}


public find
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
    Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();

    String key = "be";

    while( !StdIn.isEmpty() )
        {
        String item = StdIn.readString();
        if( !item.equals("-") )
            s.push( item );
        else 
            StdOut.print( s.pop() + " " );
        }

    s.find1( s, key );
     }

     public boolean find1( Stack<String> s, String key )
    {
    for( String item : s )
        {
        if( item.equals( key ) )
            return true;
        }
    return false;
    }
}
```

this is all my code

Comment: It would help if you show your code.

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: If you get a good grade, do you upvote the answer?

Comment: compiles just fine for me. What compiler are you using? Sun's?

Comment: huh... a have no idea, im using Ubuntu 10.10. what terminal command will give me the compiler?

Comment: i am commiling it in emacs. dont know if it will make any difference

Comment: the problem is your Stack class does not implement Iterable, it doesn't override the `public iterator()` method and therefore there is no iterator passed to the for loop when you do this: `for String item : Stack<String> s)`. You can get around this by adding a HashSet that stores your stack items, implementing Iterable and overriding the iterator method to return the HashSet's iterator. Then you should be able to use the for-each loop on your class.

Answer (score 13):

Are you using an iterator instead of an array?

http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with

> You cannot just pass an `Iterator` into the enhanced for-loop. The 2nd line of the following will generate a compilation error:
>
> ```
>     Iterator<Penguin> it = colony.getPenguins();
>     for (Penguin p : it) {
> ```
>
> The error:
>
> ```
>     BadColony.java:36: foreach not applicable to expression type
>         for (Penguin p : it) {
> ```

I just saw that you have your own Stack class. You do realize that there is one already in the SDK, right? http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html
You need to implement `Iterable` interface in order to use this form of the `for` loop: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your for-construct looks like this

```
    LinkedList<String> stringList = new  LinkedList<String>();
    //populate stringList

    for(String item : stringList)
    {
        // do something with item
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without code this is just a grasp at straws.

If you're trying to write your own list-find method, it would be like this

```
<E> boolean contains(E e, List<E> list) {

    for(E v : list) if(v.equals(e)) return true;
    return false;
}
```