# Enhanced for-loop does not accept Iterator

Tags: java, foreach, iteration

Excuse me if this has been asked before. My search did not bring up any other similar question. This is something that surprised me in Java.

Apparently, the enhanced for-loop only accepts an array or an instance of `java.lang.Iterable`. It does not accept a `java.util.Iterator` as a valid obj reference to iterate over. For example, Eclipse shows an error message for the following code. It says: "**Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable**"

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();
mySet.add("dummy");
mySet.add("test");
Iterator<String> strings = mySet.iterator();
for (String str : strings) {
    // Process str value ...
}
```

Why would this be so? I want to know why the enhanced for-loop was designed to work this way. Although an Iterator is not a collection, it can be used to return one element at a time from a collection. Note that the only method in the `java.lang.Iterable` interface is `Iterator<T> iterator()` which returns an `Iterator`. Here, I am directly handing it an `Iterator`. I know that `hasNext()` and `next()` can be used but using the enhanced for-loop makes it look cleaner.

One thing I understand now is that I could use the enhanced for-loop directly over `mySet`. So I don't even need the extra call to get an `Iterator`. So, that would be the way to code this, and yes - it does make some sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [foreach not applicable to expression type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783339/foreach-not-applicable-to-expression-type)

Comment: To explain the eclipse warning: `Iterable != Iterator`

Comment: Edited the question to explain why this is not a duplicate of [foreach not applicable to expression type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783339/foreach-not-applicable-to-expression-type). And @gnomed - I do know that `Iterable != Iterator` :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The enhanced for loop was part of [JSR 201](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=201). From that page, you can download the proposed final draft documents, which include a FAQ section directly addressing your question:

> Appendix I. Design FAQ
>
> 1. Why can't I use the enhanced for statement with an Iterator (rather
>      than an Iterable or array)?
>
> Two reasons: (1) The construct would not
>   provide much in the way on syntactic improvement if you had an
>   explicit iterator in your code, and (2) Execution of the loop would
>   have the "side effect" of advancing (and typically exhausting) the
>   iterator. In other words, the enhanced for statement provides a
>   simple, elegant, solution for the common case of iterating over a
>   collection or array, and does not attempt to address more complicated
>   cases, which are better addressed with the traditional for statement.
>
> 2. Why can't I use the enhanced for statement to:
>
>    - remove elements as I traverse a collection ("filtering")?
>    - simultaneously iterate over multiple collections or arrays?
>    - modify the current slot in an array or list?
>
> See Item 1 above. The expert group considered these cases, but
>   opted for a simple, clean extension that dose(sic) one thing well. The
>   design obeys the "80-20 rule" (it handles 80% of the cases with 20% of
>   the effort). If a case falls into the other 20%, you can always use an
>   explicit iterator or index as you've done in the past.

In other words, the committee chose to limit the scope of the proposal, and some features that one could imagine being part of the proposal didn't make the cut.

Comment: Thanks, Kenster. That is what I wanted to know. Everyone else wants to teach me what is wrong and what is right, while I wanted to know why. :-) Maybe I should have been clearer in the question.

Answer (score 6):

> The enhanced for loop was introduced in Java 5 as a simpler way to
>   iterate through all the elements of a Collection [or an array].

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/enhanced-for-loops.html

An iterator is not a collection of elements,

> it is an object that enables a programmer to traverse a container.
>   An iterator may be thought of as a type of pointer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator

So enhanced for loops work by going through all the elements in a structure that *contains* elements, while an iterator doesn't contain elements, it acts more like a pointer.

Comment: That is not a complete answer. Although an Iterator is not a collection and does not **contain** elements, it sure **can** be used to return elements one at a time and that is the basic purpose of the enhanced for-loop. Obviously, it knows about a collection. This looks like a design decision. I was wondering **why** it was decided to be like this. @Kenster's answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: Notice that Iterable is not a Collection or array either.  Iterables are things with methods which return Iterators.  I would expect that at least 95% of Iterable implementations simply return their sole constructor argument to work around this quirk of the enhanced `for`.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are creating an iterator but not using it properly. As to answer your question of why the exception is being thrown- it's from the line:

```
 for (String str : strings) {
```

"strings" is an iterator here, not a collection that you can iterate through. So you have a few options you can iterate through the set by using an enhanced for loop:

```
for(String myString : mySet){
    //do work
}
```

or you can iterate through the set using an iterator:

```
Iterator<String> strings = mySet.iterator();
while(strings.hasNext()){
    //do work
}
```

hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes because you are trying to iterate over an ***Iterator***, and not a ***List*** or ***Collection***. If you want to use the ***Iterator***, i recommend you to use it ***next()*** and ***hasNext()*** methods:

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();
mySet.add("dummy");
mySet.add("test");
Iterator<String> strings = mySet.iterator();
while(strings.hasNext()){
    String temp = strings.next();
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Comment: While this shows the asker how to use a loop with an `Iterator` object, it does little to explain the difference between how the enhanced for loop traverses a `Collection` and why an `Iterator` cannot be applied that way.