# Iterating issue of java.lang.Iterable instance

Tags: java, iterator

My Code

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    private List<T> persons = new ArrayList<T>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test<Test> ob = new Test<Test>();
        ob.persons.add(ob);

        for (Test t : ob.iterator()) {

            System.out.println();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {

        return persons.iterator();
    }

}
```

Error:

```
Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
```

What's adifference between two, Why A can't be legal and B is working ?

```
    for (Test t : ob.iterator()) {   ----------------------A

        System.out.println();

    }


while (ob.iterator().hasNext()) { -------------------------- B 

        System.out.println();

   }
```

Want to know why A underlying code is not working ?  Is something different happening in for loop ? `While` and `for` both are provided the same iterator state to be iterated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enhanced for-loop does not accept Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348033/enhanced-for-loop-does-not-accept-iterator)

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598219/java-why-cant-iterate-over-an-iterator

Answer (score 2):

Drop the iterator call:

```
for (Test t : ob) {
```

You have to give the for loop an Iter*able* (or an array), not an Iter*ator*.

---

This:

```
while (ob.iterator().hasNext()) {
```

Almost certainly doesn't do what you mean. Each time the loop guard is evaluated, this creates a new iterator, at the start of the iteration, and checks if there is a "next" element. Unless `ob` is empty initially, this will continue to be true on each iteration (unless you remove an element from `ob` inside the loop).

The (probably) correct way to do this is:

```
Iterator<T> iterator = ob.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) { // use the same iterator instance throughout iteration.
  T next = iterator.next();
}
```

Comment: ob in for loop, how its iterable ? Just becasue its implemented Iterable interface. How ob did return iterable ? In while, it gets called explicitly.

Comment: @Maria `ob` is iterable because it's a variable of type `Test<T>`, a class which implements `Iterable<T>`. The enhanced for loop is syntactic sugar which gets translated into a for loop: the compiler inserts the `iterator()` call. See [the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).

Comment: Is it a different ways of doing same thing ? Am I wrong ?