# How do I solve a for-each not applicable to expression type?

Tags: java, foreach

The `removePanel ()` is used to get the components in the `mainPanel` using `getComponent ()` and an enhanced loop. Then check which components are visible & call the `removeLayoutComponent ()` on that component.

***THIS IS THE REMOVEJPANEL METHOD***

```
public void removeJPanel () {
 for (Component comp : mainPanel.getComponent (number)) {
    if (comp.isVisible () == true) {
        card.removeLayoutComponent (comp);
        number++;
    } else {
      System.out.print("It didn't work!");
    }
 }
}
```

`mainPanel` uses a card layout, JPanels from the `panel` array are then added onto `mainPanel`.

***THIS IS THE CODE WHERE I CREATE THE MAINPANEL & ADD JPANELS ONTO IT***

```
public TicTacToeFrame () {
 if (badge.num == 0) {
   playerX = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter Player X name: ");
   playerO = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter Player O name: ");
   badge.setLabel (playerX);
 }
   mainPanel = new JPanel ();//THIS IS WHERE I CREATE MAINPANEL
   mainPanel.setLayout (card);//THIS IS WHERE CARDLAYOUT IS SET AS LAYOUT MANAGER
   panels [0] = new JPanel (new GridLayout (3, 3, 0, 0));
   panels [1] = new JPanel (new GridLayout (3, 3, 0, 0));
   panels [2] = new JPanel (new GridLayout (3, 3, 0, 0));
   JPanelArray ();

   panels [0].setBorder (new LineBorder (Color.red, 1));
   panels [1].setBorder (new LineBorder (Color.red, 1));
   panels [2].setBorder (new LineBorder (Color.red, 1));

   mainPanel.add (panels [0], "one");//JPANELS FROM THE PANEL ARRAY ARE ADDED TO THE MAINPANEL
   mainPanel.add (panels [1], "two");
   mainPanel.add (panels [2], "three");

   badge.jlblStatus.setBorder (new LineBorder (Color.yellow, 1));

   add (mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   add (badge.jlblStatus, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

The expected result was for the player to click a JDialog button and for the `removePanel ()` to be executed. Instead what happened was the current panel did not get removed & a `for-each not applicable to expression type` compilation error occurred.

***THIS IS WHERE REMOVEJPANEL () IS CALLED***

```
public void replayDialog () {
   int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (this, "Do you want to play again ?", "TicTacToe", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
   if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) { 
       frame.removeJPanel ();
       frame.newCells = null;
       label.num++;
       frame.JPanelArray ();
   } else if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
        frame.gameOver = true;
   }     
}
```

***COMPILATION ERROR***

```
.\TicTacToeFrame.java:139: error: for-each not applicable to expression type
     for (Component comp : mainPanel.getComponent (number)) {
                                              ^
 required: array or java.lang.Iterable
 found:    Component
1 error
```

I found this [foreach not applicable to expression type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783339/foreach-not-applicable-to-expression-type) on this site, but this doesn't meet my needs as I struggled to understand what was on the page since I am still a beginner in java.

Comment: `getComponent()` returns a single component.  What do you think you're going to be looping over?

Comment: Oh i should've used getComponents () instead

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand what u mean by "Arrays.asList(getComponents ())". Can you elaborate please.

Answer (score 1):

The `JPanel.getComponent(int)` just returns one component, the one at the location for the index you pass in.  If you want to iterate over all the components in the JPanel you can use `JPanel.getComponents`, like this:

```
public void removeJPanel () {
 Component[] components : mainPanel.getComponents();
 for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
    Component comp = components[i];
    if (comp.isVisible () == true) {
        card.removeLayoutComponent (comp);
        number++;
    } else {
      System.out.print("It didn't work!");
    }
 }
}
```